# .jar File won't work for some reason

Tags: powershell, java, jar

I wrote and compiled a java program and the resulting files are (HelloWorldSwing.java), (HelloWorldSwing.class) & (HelloWorldSwing$1.class) as shown in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP30T.png)

The files are in a package called (start) as shown in the directory path. I tested the program using cmd and it works just fine. However, when I tried to create a .jar file it would create the file but the file won't open.

I separately tried to include the .java file alone, the .class(es) alone, and everything together.. Nothing would make the .jar work.

The .jar file WAS created, but here's what I wrote in the powershell anyways -

```
jar -cf Run.jar *.java
```

OR

```
jar -cf Run.jar *.class
```

OR

```
jar -cf Run.jar *.java *.class
```

In each of these cases, the jar file was created but it wouldn't run for some reason.

Comment: What version of java have you got installed?

Comment: java version 1.8.0_111